# Error : Field "S_MARA-MATNR" is unkown during FOR statement

Tags: abap

```
DATA: t_mara type STANDARD TABLE OF mara WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA(t_data1) = VALUE ty_data( FOR s_mara IN t_mara ( s_mara–matnr ) ).
```

I am trying to implement a similar code using `FOR statement` but I am getting an error that the field is unknown in the work area even though it would be declared inline.

Can you please let me know what went wrong? This is my first time I am facing this error on FOR loop.

Comment: Just post a minimal working example and the exact error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure because you are not providing too much detail but try this:

```
DATA t_mara type STANDARD TABLE OF mara WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(t_data1) = VALUE ty_data( FOR s_mara IN t_mara ( matnr = s_mara-matnr ) ).
```

Comment: For the record, what's missing from the code in the question is the `matnr =` part. The FOR-statement needs to know which column of `t_data1` gets mapped to `s_mara-matnr`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. i had missed the mapping field to the table data selection. Problem solved.

It's really great to be using the new syntax in my code.

Comment: @RaviRishie Accepting the answer makes people happy :)